# node js Javascript object showing in body of HTML but not in terminal and console

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I've been banging my head against a wall for days on this, and I keep getting closer and closer but I'm not quite there.  I'm taking an online course and am trying to replicate an example project from lesson video.  The problem is that the code works in the video but the code they show you is flat out wrong and missing all sorts of key components.

What I have so far is a form that submits the fav element of the object.  When I go to the page (before submitting the form) I can see in the console and the terminal:

```
  {
    animal: 'lion',
    fact: "a lion's roar can be heard five miles away",
    fav: {}
  }
```

So it's correctly calling the data from /fakeAnimalData.  When I submit the form, I get two thirds of the object (again) and then another object with the fav element.  I need these two objects to be combined into one, but the code isn't doing that.

```
[{"animal":"lion","fact":"a lion's roar can be heard five miles away","fav":{}},{"fav":"lions are big"}]
```

Nothing is shown in the console.  And in the terminal I only get:

```
{ animal: undefined, fact: undefined, fav: 'lions are big' }
```

Another more minor problem is that in the video the object does NOT appear in the body of the HTML.  The form remains there and the object is only shown in the console and terminal.  I think this is because my routes are set up incorrrectly but I'm not sure.  As of now, the objects replace the form and I would like to still see the form and only see the complete object in the console and the terminal.

I hope I explained that correctly.  This is my code:

server.js:

```
projectData = {};

/* Express to run server and routes */
const express = require('express');

/* Start up an instance of app */
const app = express();

/* Dependencies */
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
/* Middleware*/
app.use(express.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
const cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors());

/* Initialize the main project folder*/
app.use(express.static('project1'));

const port = 8000;
/* Spin up the server*/
const server = app.listen(port, listening);
 function listening(){
    // console.log(server);
    console.log(`running on localhost: ${port}`);
  };

// GET route

const animalData = [];
const fakeData = {animal: "lion", fact: "a lion's roar can be heard five miles away"};

app.get('/fakeAnimalData', getFakeData);

function getFakeData(req, res) {
  console.log(fakeData);
  res.send(fakeData);
};

app.get('/all', getData);

function getData(req, res){
  res.send(animalData)
  console.log(animalData)
}

// function sendData (request, response) {
//  response.send(projectData);
// };

// POST route
app.post('/add', callBack);

function callBack(req,res){
  res.send('POST received');
}



// POST an animal
const data = [];


  // TODO-Call Function

app.post('/addAnimal', addAnimal);

app.route('/')
  .get(function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile('index.html', {root: 'project1'})
  })
  .post(addAnimal)

//app.route('/addAnimal')
//  .get(function (req, res) {
//    res.sendFile('index.html', {root: 'project1'})
//  })
//  .post(addAnimal)

function addAnimal(req, res){

  newEntry = {
    animal: req.body.animal,
    fact: req.body.fact,
    fav: req.body.fav
  }

  //data.push(req.body);
//  res.status(200).send(req.body);
  animalData.push(newEntry)
  res.send(animalData)
  console.log(animalData)
};
```

app.js:

```
function performAction(e){
const fav = document.getElementById('fav').value;

getAnimal('/fakeAnimalData')
.then(async function(data){
    console.log(data);
  let res = await postData('/addAnimal', {animal: data.animal, fact: data.fact, fav: fav});
  console.log(res);
});
};

const getAnimal = async (url) =>{
  const res = await fetch(url);
  try {
    const data = await res.json();
    console.log(data)
    return data;
  } catch(error) {
    console.log()
  }
};

/* Function to POST data */
const postData = async ( url = '', data = {})=>{
    console.log(data);
      const response = await fetch(url, {
      method: 'POST', // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
      credentials: 'same-origin', // include, *same-origin, omit
      headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(data), // body data type must match "Content-Type" header        
    });

      try {
        const newData = await response.json();
        console.log(newData);
        // console.log(newData);
        return newData
        console.log(await response.json());
        return await response.json()
      }catch(error) {
      console.log("error", error);
      // appropriately handle the error
      };
  };

  // TODO-Call Function
getAnimal('/fakeAnimalData')
.then(async function(data){
    console.log(data);
  let res = await postData('/addAnimal', {animal: data.animal, fact: data.fact, fav: fav});
  console.log(res);
});
```

I feel like I'm close but the pieces aren't coming together.  I cannot begin to tell you how much I would appreciate any kind of guidence on this that you can give me.

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**‍ If you only need to combine** your `animalData`, then you sould do this: Change you type of `anymalData` from `array` to `object`.

So, your code will looks like this:

- **Before:** `const animalData = [];`
- **After:** `let animalData = {};`

**‍ After you change** your `animalData` from `array` to `object`, now you've to change your function `addAnimal`. So, it's will looks like this code below:

```js
function addAnimal(req, res){
    // make sure it's not empty
    console.log(req.body);

    // combine your req.body with animalData
    // Object.assign(animalData, req.body); <= the second option
    animalData = { ...animalData, ...req.body }

    // send response to the client
    res.status(200).send(animalData)
};
```

**After you change** your function `addAnimal` with the code above , Now, you can try again.

I Hope it can help you .

Answer (score 0):

Can you send the method you want to send and the result you want to arrive?

If you want to use the **/addAnimal** post method:

```
var request = require('request');
var options = {
  'method': 'POST',
  'url': 'http://localhost:8000/addAnimal',
  'headers': {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({"animal":"lion","fact":"a lion's roar can be heard five miles away","fav":{}})

};
request(options, function (error, response) { 
  if (error) throw new Error(error);
  console.log(response.body);
});
```

In this way, every request sent will be pushed to the "animalData" array that you define globally.